# Bigquery calculate split from the beginning of month until end of month/current date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some problems, I want to calculate amount split from the beginning of month until end of month/current date and split by product like this :

data :

| Date_payment | product | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-01 | aa | 10 |
| 2020-02-01 | aa | 20 |
| 2020-02-03 | bb | 5 |
| 2020-02-29 | bb | 5 |
| 2020-03-01 | aa | 4 |
| 2020-03-03 | aa | 3 |
| 2020-03-03 | bb | 1 |

let say Current date is 2020-03-05
i want to calculate split by product and by month from the beginning of month until end of month/current date

my expectation result is :

| Date_Report | product | Total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-01 | aa | 30 |
| 2020-02-02 | aa | 30 |
| 2020-02-03 | aa | 30 |
| 2020-02-03 | bb | 5 |
| 2020-02-04 | aa | 30 |
| 2020-02-04 | bb | 5 |

....so on until..

| Date_Report | product | Totalamount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-29 | aa | 30 |
| 2020-02-29 | bb | 10 |
| 2020-03-01 | aa | 4 |
| 2020-03-02 | aa | 4 |
| 2020-03-03 | aa | 7 |
| 2020-03-03 | bb | 1 |
| 2020-03-04 | aa | 7 |
| 2020-03-04 | bb | 1 |
| 2020-03-05 | aa | 7 |
| 2020-03-05 | bb | 1 |

I want to see the total amount of each day from the beginning of the month to the end of the month for each month.

anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the days, cross join with the products and bring in the existing data:

```
select report_date, p.product, coalesce(month_amount, 0) as month_amount
from (unnest(generate_date_array(date('2020-01-01'), current_date, interval 1 day)) report_date cross join
     (select distinct product from t) p left join
     (select date_trunc(report_date, month) as mon, product, 
             sum(amount) as month_amount
      from t
      group by 1, 2
     ) t
     on t.mon = date_trunc(report_date, month) and t.product = p.product;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do the job:

```
SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC(Date_payment, MONTH) AS payment_month,
  product,
  SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM
  transactions
GROUP BY
  payment_month,
  product
ORDER BY
  payment_month,
  product
```

With the table you provided the result is:

[image]

Comment: i mean I want to see the total amount of each day from the beginning of the month to the end of the month for each month

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, sorry I didn't understand what you needed. I therefore think @Gordon_linoff answer is what your looking for

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your columns are as below :

```
create table "Example"
( "DatePayment" date,
 "Product" nvarchar(5),
 "Amount" int
);
```

Your logic could be(please change to BigQuery syntax):

```
DO BEGIN

DECLARE FIRSTDATE,LASTDATE DATE;
SELECT TO_DATE(YEAR(MIN("DatePayment"))||'-'||MONTH(MIN("DatePayment"))||'-01') INTO FIRSTDATE FROM "Example";
SELECT LAST_DAY(MAX("DatePayment")) INTO LASTDATE FROM "Example";

VAR1= SELECT D."DT",E."Product",case when S."Amount" is null then 0 else S."Amount" end as "Amount_CC" FROM 
    (select "GENERATED_PERIOD_START" AS "DT" from "SERIES_GENERATE_DATE"('INTERVAL 1 DAY' ,:FIRSTDATE, :LASTDATE ) ) D 
 CROSS JOIN  ( SELECT DISTINCT "Product" FROM "Example" ) E
 LEFT OUTER JOIN  ( select "DatePayment","Product","Amount" from "Example" ) S
 ON D."DT"=S."DatePayment" AND E."Product"=S."Product";

VAR2= select *  ,  SUM("Amount_CC") OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH("DT"), "Product" ORDER BY "DT"
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  AND CURRENT ROW )  AS "Amount" from :VAR1 ;

select "DT" as "DatePayment","Product","Amount" from :VAR2  where "Amount" <>0 order by "DT","Product";

END;
```

You will get the result for all months in your dataset.
Results below :
[image]

[image]